# pull all contacts out of Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, contacts

I'm trying to pull all my contacts out of Outlook.
I have tried many things but nothing works for me,
I would love to hear from your experience what is the trivial way to do this.
This is one way I tried to do:

```
Using SPIRE.EMAIL


// Create an imapclient with host, user and password

        ImapClient client = new ImapClient();

        client.Host = "outlook.office365.com";

        client.Username = "#Your email address";

        client.Password = "#Your email password";

        client.ConnectionProtocols = ConnectionProtocols.Ssl;

        client.Port = 143;

        client.Connect();

        client.Select("Inbox");

        // Get a collection of messages

        var addressSet = new HashSet<string>();

        ImapMessageCollection msg = client.GetAllMessageHeaders();

        for (int i = 0; i < msg.Count; i++)

        {

            string address = msg[i].From.Address;

            addressSet.Add(address);

        }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What are you expecting? In any case, this will return all the addresses you ever received emails from, not the contents of your address book.

Comment: I look forward to receive all the addresses ...
I get an error in this line:
 client.Connect();
 Error: Unable to connect
 thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use an IMAP client manually for this? Outlook.com doesn't use IMAP, but MS Exchange, as far as I know.